# What is the performance and How data collection feature works internally

Tags: kaa

From the references, I come to know that KAA support the data collection features to store/save the historical/logs data to the server using various plugins.

A Few doubts are in my mind that are as below

-How it works internally??

-What is the internal architecture of Data collection??

-Can KAA support/processed millions of data logs (with out latency)?

-If i use KAFKA as a log appender, Can KAA publish millions of logs on KAFKA as it received. (Without latency) ?

-Is there any performance degrade?? if KAA received millions of logs simultaneously??

Answer (score 0):

To knew all about Kaa data collection feature, refer to the [Data collection](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Data-collection/) documentation page.
Speaking about latency, you should understand that latency always presents in real systems. For performance improvement, you can 
use Kaa in [cluster mode](http://gamovcoder.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Administration-guide/System-installation/Cluster-setup/).